# removing files except some in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I was trying to delete some files in a bash script and exclude some I still need afterwards. This is what I came up with:

```
if [ $var1 -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$var1 = 0"
    shopt -s extglob
    rm /home/someone/!(file1.txt|file2.png|file3.pdf|file4.csv)
else
    echo "$var1 = 1"
    shopt -s extglob
    rm -rf /home/someone/!(file1.txt|file2.png|file3.pdf|file4.csv)
fi
```

It is working if I execute it manually on the shell, but in the script it does not even call the if-loop. As soon as I comment out the lines containing the "!" it works.

Comment: Are you sure the script runs in `/bin/bash` and not some other shell?

Comment: yes I added the `#!/bin/bash` at the top of my script.

Comment: And how do you run the script?

Comment: Usually it is called by a php-script.
But to test it i called it with /home/someone/script.sh

Comment: Is this code in a function? if it is, you have to move the `shopt -s extglob` out of the function: [that's a caveat of the way Bash parses the code](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob).

Comment: Wow that was it..... Thank you!
Can you write it as an answer, so i can mark it as correct? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot turn the `extglob` shell option from within a block or a function. E.g., this will fail:

```
shopt -u extglob

f() {
    shopt -s extglob
    echo *+(a)*
}
f
```

The reason is that the command `shopt -s extglob` is not executed when the block is parsed… and the parser will hence complain when it encounters the extended glob `+(a)`. See [the relevant section of the `glob` page on Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob):

> `extglob` **changes the way certain characters are parsed. It is necessary to have a newline (not just a semicolon) between `shopt -s extglob` and any subsequent commands to use it.** You cannot enable extended globs inside a group command that uses them, because the entire block is parsed before the `shopt` is evaluated. Note that the typical function body is a group command. An unpleasant workaround could be to use a subshell command list as the function body.

If you really want this behavior, though, you can use `eval`, but that's really not recommended at all! Instead, move the `shopt -s extglob` out of the block. In fact, it is customary to put the shell options at the beginning of the script and use them throughout the script (when applicable). I don't think you'll run into any problems if you use `extglob` throughout the script.

Answer (score 0):

As [@choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012837/removing-files-except-some-in-a-bash-script/38013378#comment63468202_38012837) is hinting towards, you need to run your script either as **`bash my_script.sh`** or **`./my_script.sh`** to run it with Bash. If you run `sh my_script.sh` the shell may not support `extglob`.

A useful way to tell what's actually happening is to add `set -o xtrace` to the top of the script (after the shebang line). That should tell you what actually gets executed. I'd also add `set -o errexit` to make sure the script stops at the first failing command, and [quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) the reference to `$var1`.

Comment: As i mentioned already, I am calling it with /home/someone/script.sh (./script.sh).
I added your suggestions, seeing what I already did before.
The script stops at line 29 with `bash: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `('`
And no, there are no syntax errors. It only appears when the "!" appear in the script.

Comment: "Line 29" means this is not the whole code, and it's likely the error is elsewhere. Please post the whole script.